# Using gsub and paste to remove a portion of text from certain variables

Tags: r, rename

I am using `gsub` and `paste` to change the columns of a dataframe. In particular, for all the columns ending by `.h`, where `h` is a number from `0` to `23` I use the following script (for example for variable `p.1`)

```
h <- 1
gsub(paste(".", h, sep = ""), "", "p.1")
# "p"          # correct!
```

The script should not work for all the variables that do not end with `.h`. For example

```
h <- 1
gsub(paste(".", h, sep = ""), "", "prob10")
# "pro0"          # not correct!
```

However, this code yields "pro0", in stead of "prob10". Similarly,

```
h <- 0
gsub(paste(".", h, sep = ""), "", "prob10")
# "prob"          # not correct!
```

gives me the wrong answer. I don't understand why `gsub` does not work (in first place) and why the last two examples give different results. Thank you.

Comment: I think that the answer is that I should use "[[:punct:]]" instead of "."

Comment: This is because of regex behavior. `. ` is a special character, which means 'anything' in a regex. In order for it to just mean dot, you have to escape it. Try pasting `'\\.'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well gsub works, just not as u would expect it to.
because "." is a metacharacter.

> The simplest example of a metacharacter is the full stop.
>
> '.' 
>   The full stop character matches any single character of any sort (apart
>   from a newline).
>
> For example, the regular expression ".at" means: any
>   letter, followed by the letter 'a', followed by the letter 't'.
>
> ".at" => The **cat** **sat** on the **mat** .

(see https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node84.html)

The working code for you would be

```
for (h in 23:0) 
{gsub(paste(".", h, sep = ""), "", "p.1", fixed = TRUE)
}
```